# How to make "Created by" editable

Tags: list

I created a list. As I sometimes need to create list for others. Is it possible to edit "created by" afterwards or make a duplicate column with default field = "created by" and then allows editing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Created By** is read-only field that can not be editable but its value can be only changed via code or PowerShell.

**To can do this via code check the following MSDN article**

- [Can we update the values of "Created By", "Modified By" columns in SharePoint lists ?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2008/03/14/can-we-update-the-values-of-created-by-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists/)

**To can do this via PowerShell check the following MSDN article**

- [Updating the “Created By” and “Modified By” Columns in SharePoint lists using POWERSHELL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tadd/2008/05/22/updating-the-created-by-and-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists-using-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

Create another people & group column and have that column reference the "Created By" column in a workflow or using the default value. That's the only way you'll be able to make a column like that "editable"